# .ics file via Data in PHP Laravel Mail

Tags: php, html, laravel, icalendar

I am trying to create a link to download a .ics file based on the Data for iCalendar event.

Here's the code in jsfiddle which is working independently but not working in Mail which I'm sending.

```html
<a href="data:text/calendar;charset=utf8;base64,QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU9OOjIuMA0KQkVHSU46VkVWRU5UDQpVSUQ6ZWViODI5NGI0MjQzNWI3NDAwMDdjOGE0YzM5OGQ5NzkNClNVTU1BUlk6U2tpcHBlZCB0b3BpY3MgZnJvbSBsYXN0IHNlc3Npb24NCkRUU1RBUlQ7VFpJRD1BbWVyaWNhL05ld19Zb3JrOjIwMjEwOTE3VDEwMzAwMA0KRFRFTkQ7VFpJRD1BbWVyaWNhL05ld19Zb3JrOjIwMjEwOTE3VDExMzAwMA0KREVTQ1JJUFRJT046RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gRGVzY3JpcHRpb24gRGVzY3JpcHRpb24gRGVzY3JpcHRpb24gRGVzY3JpcHRpb24gRGVzY3JpcHRpb24gDQpFTkQ6VkVWRU5UDQpFTkQ6VkNBTEVOREFS" download="Cal.ics">
<button type="button">iCalendar</button>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Groovy_Guy/0etmh9sb/

I want to use the Data value and allow users to download .ics file on click button.

Comment: `button` in `a` is invalid HTML to begin with, you can not nest those two interactive elements into each other. The problem here however is more likely that mail clients / web interfaces probably simply block this, I suppose.